# Inserted GIFs photos do not animate in Microsoft Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, gif, animation

I make lots of proposals on a daily basis. I would like to know how I can put animated photos that would play in Microsoft Word and subsequently in my PDF documents.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? For instance: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/animate-text-or-objects-305a1c94-83b1-4778-8df5-fcf7a9b7b7c6

Comment: Also, Animation in PDFs is NOT the same as that in Word docs, and unless you have a paid for Adobe license, I'd guess the average PDF converter, much less the PDF printer function in Word, cannot retain animation in the conversion.

Comment: It seems that pdf does not support gif animation.

Answer (score 1):

#### Inserted GIFs photos do not animate in Microsoft Word

**How to insert animated GIF in Word document**

> To insert an animated GIF as a background in Word documents, follow
> these steps:
>
> - Launch Microsoft Word.
> - Click the Insert tab, click Picture, and choose This Device.
> - Select the GIF you have downloaded and click Insert.
> - Click the Picture Format tab, click the Position button, and select Position in the middle with square text wrapping.
> - Click the Layout options button and select Behind text.
> - Now type on the GIF background.

Source: [How to insert animated GIF in Word document](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-insert-animated-gif-in-word-document)

> To play animated GIF files, you must open the files in the
> Preview/Properties window. To do this, select the animated GIF file,
> and then on the View menu, click Preview/Properties.
>
> If the GIF does not play, try re-saving the animated GIF in the
> collection in which you want to put it. On the GIF, click the
> down-arrow, and then click Preview/Properties.

Source: [My animated GIF won't play - Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/my-animated-gif-won-t-play-377bfae5-86fc-4de6-b2c5-019691e8c213)

> It is only recently that Word offered the ability to play animated GIF files. Previously the only way to do so was to save the document as a web page and view in a browser. Have you considered embedding a video file instead? Insert > Object > Create from File.

Source: [Playing GIF's in Word versions prior to 365](https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/48622-playing-gifs-word-versions-prior-365-a.html)

> **Why is my GIF not working on Word?**
>
> In Microsoft Word, if a GIF is not working, it means that you have
> tried to insert it using the Online Pictures option when trying to
> insert the picture into the document. For the GIF to work, you must
> download the GIF from a site and insert it into the word document.

Source: [How to insert animated GIF in Word document](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-insert-animated-gif-in-word-document)

Answer (score 0):

Other answer covers MS Word well, so here are salient points for PDF.

Gif images can be stored as static bitmaps, so like thumb-books you need to run pdf images by stepping pages and few (if any) PDF viewers include a 24-30 page per second timer! Here is a gif as a PDF https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/blob/master/300px-Tower_of_Hanoi_4-v3.1.2.pdf

Rich Media such as 3D or Mp4 embedding is possible to run say an AVI or other converted "Video Formats", generally depreciated as in part due to  the demise of SWFlash, but still runnable in some PDF Viewers such as Okular or Acrobat etc. Here is an Example of a "short" included in a PDF page.

[image]

For 3D animation you need to use Acrobat DC viewer  or close equivalent https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/raw/master/Acrobat%203D%20test%20-%20Laughing%20Porpoise.pdf
[image]